# What are good vegan sources of saturated fats?

Tags: veganism, health, fats

Saturated fats have been shown to be [less harmful](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1208952/) than we have been led to believe. In fact, some believe red meat is to blame for skewing research results against saturated fats:

> Conclusion: The results support the hypothesis that animal fat, especially fat from red meat, is associated with an elevated risk of advanced prostate cancer.<sup>[[source]](https://academic.oup.com/jnci/article-abstract/85/19/1571/934132/A-Prospective-Study-of-Dietary-Fat-and-Risk-of)</sup>

So, what vegan foods provide a good amount of saturated fats?

Comment: There is a big difference between "Plant-based saturated fats aren't harmful" and "they are more essential." The former appears to be supported to the literature you link to. The latter does not (at least yet) seem to be supported by such literature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Coconut oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coconut_oil)

85-91% saturates

[Cocoa butter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_butter)

57-64% saturates

[Palm oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_oil)<sup>1</sup>

~50% saturates

---

<sup>1</sup>Although many veg*ns avoid this. See  [Why do many vegans avoid products which contain palm oil?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/333/why-do-many-vegans-avoid-products-which-contain-palm-oil)

Comment: Why did you misspell "vegans"? You wrote, "veg*ans"

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon I meant vegans and vegetarians - using "*" as a glob meaning any characters