# Food products with sparingly milked cows, to ensure the success and spread, and the preservation, of their population

Tags: ethics, animal-welfare, lacto-vegetarianism, milk

What could people eat, to ensure a loss in population and its friendly, happy, heart warning, dynamics of cows would be brought to an end.

Would the solution be to market, and agree to consume, products, containing some percentage, even in small doses, in every food item, of milk (with each cow, sparingly milked)?

Would this be a solution, be sustainable, and can we make improvements on this solution?

Can we support, cows, and their families?

Comment: Are there lots of food items that contain significant amounts of milk other than cheese (and that's pretty much only milk)? I suppose rice pudding does but otherwise the problem is less about food and more about milk itself and simply eating less dairy. I'm not sure that's a terribly satisfying answer but this is a Q&A site and I'm not sure it's a suitable starting point for a campaign if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Eating less dairy does not ensure the cows from which the milk comes are not overmilked, leading to poor calf health.

Comment: And one reason for going vegetarian or vegan is to ensure cow population health.

Answer (score 2):

Cattle (Bos taurus), like cats and dogs, are not natural species.

As of 2021, [there's one and a half *trillion* cattle](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/cattle-livestock-count-heads?tab=table).

We have an unsustainable large number of cows on Earth. There are so many cattle bred by humans that humans have [cut down enormous stretches of forest](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/399/which-one-promotes-the-most-deforestation-raising-crops-or-animal-husbandry/937#937)  to feed them, they produce vast quantities of methane that are driving the climate catastrophe, and they are polluting waterways and killing fish.

> Can we support, cows, and their families?

The most ethical way to support cows is to have them [fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutering), let them grow old, and vastly reduce their population to a sustainable number (thousands or millions but not billions or trillions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But castrating a bull is not exactly ethical. Furthermore, what do you mean by "not natural species"? I was not aware that there are natural and non natural species. Thanks.

Comment: Humans have created many species through select breeding. Examples include dogs, cats, and dairy cattle. Since we created them, most vegetarians argue that "spay/neuter and release" programs are the more ethical choice than letting them breed and suffer.

Comment: Are you saying that their suffering is in part due to the way we have bred them? Can you give me some examples? Thanks.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson examples of other species that have been bread by humans to maximize economic outcomes (at the expense of the animal's welfare) include: sheep, chickens, pigs, horses, and fish. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_breeding

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson see https://www.ciwf.org.uk/media/3818641/impact-of-selection-on-health-and-welfare-of-dairy-cattle.pdf for info on the poor health and suffering of modern dairy cows due to selective breeding