# Which vegetal foods grown in Canada are good sources of fat?

Tags: veganism, fats, canada

I'm trying to buy more locally-grown foods and rely less on imports, but when it comes to sources of plant-based fat that seems to be a bit of a challenge in Canada. Relying on imports can be problematic in some cases like [palm oil](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/333/1236) where weak regulation and corporate exploitation and geographic circumstances result in destruction of wildlife habitat, or there might be concerns about welfare of human workers like the story about [cashew nut workers](https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2013/nov/02/cashew-nut-workers-pay-conditions-profits).

The largest sources of saturated fat, coconut and palm, aren't really grown in Canada but I don't really care much for saturated fat so I'm happy to just avoid those products. However, some of my favourite sources of plant-based fats (avocados, cashews, olive oil) are all imported from places like Mexico or [Vietnam](https://atlas.media.mit.edu/en/visualize/tree_map/hs92/import/can/show/200819/2016/) or [Italy](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/food-and-wine/food-trends/meet-a-canadian-oil-baron-olive-oil-that-is/article9074642/).

Are there good plant-based sources of fat that are grown and sold in Canada, or am I necessarily reliant on imports? I'm okay with trying out new foods.

*I personally have a strong preference for whole food sources rather than refined foods, but I'll accept answers about refined vegetable oils if that really is the best answer to the question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of fatty crops grown in Canada such as **[soybeans](http://soycanada.ca/industry/industry-overview/)** or **[seeds](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/oilseed-crops/)**

> The major oilseeds grown in Canada are soybeans, sunflowers, canola and flax.

Other seeds grown in Canada are for example pumpkin or hemp seeds.

In addition, there are **[nuts](http://treenuts.ca/canadatreenuts.html)**.

Many different types of nuts are grown in Canada such as hazelnuts, walnuts, and almonds (even peanuts are grown in Canada, although they are not true nuts).

Those are just some of the sources I found information from, though I'm sure there are many more!