# Is organic palm oil harmful to animals?

Tags: is-it-vegan, food, environment, fats

I know palm oil production destroy the home of monkeys. However, is this still the case for organic palm oil?

I'm talking about organic palm oil in the European Union since every country has different rules for what can be called "organic".

Comment: Related question: [Why do many vegans avoid palm oil?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/333/1236)

Comment: @Nic I saw this question but I'm specifically asking about organic palm oil here. So, unfortunately, this link doesn't help :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this case it is not about being organic, but sustainable.

https://www.rspo.org/about

---

https://theconversation.com/palm-oil-boycott-could-actually-increase-deforestation-sustainable-products-are-the-solution-106733

> If certification of palm oil becomes more popular, it will improve prospects for wildlife, including orangutans. This is why major conservation organisations – including leading orangutan charities and Greenpeace – continue to support certified palm oil, rather than a boycott. And now, environmentally conscious consumers can check where they can buy products that contain responsibly sourced palm oil.

Basing on this I think that organic palm oil is harmful to animals (much less harmful), but it could be the only way to reduce the harm in the future.

Answer (score -2):

> Organic farming is a phrase coined early in the 20th century in reaction to rapidly changing farming practices to describe what other species use, and used, to farm without synthetic chemicals

By this definition, yes palm oils is still  the cause of deaths of various animals like tigers, orangutans, [elephants](http://wwf.panda.org/our_work/forests/deforestation_fronts/deforestation_in_borneo_and_sumatra/), rhinoceros and bears by [destroying](http://www.worldwatch.org/node/6059) their habitat.

Comment: Could you include the source of your quote in your answer?

Comment: How does your claim follow from the quotation?